# ipad full screen views with orientation

Tags: ipad, orientation

In Interface Builder, what settings do I change for a view so that it fills the screen regardless of the orientation?

I am converting an iPhone app, and the views don't fill the screen unless I set the height and width to 768x1024. But when the ipad is horizontal it of course is the wrong size.